# Python Count Number of Different Elements and How Many in a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to count the number of different elements and how many of each of those elements exist in a list. The list has around 300 different elements and has a total of 1200 elements. My plan then was to plot it out in a table with plotly (https://plotly.com/python/table/). What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: You could use basic loops to achieve what you desire. Please share a minimum reproducible code incase you face any issue while trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the built-in `collections.Counter()` function for that.

```
from collections import Counter

your_list = [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1] # For example...
counted = Counter(your_list)
print(counted)
```

**Will return a dictonary:** `Counter({1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 2})`

Then just pass that dictionary to plotly

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [DefaultDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d_dict = defaultdict(int)
for element in input_list:
    d_dict[element] += 1
```

The result should be a dictionary with all unique elements as keys, and the number of times they appear in the input list as values.

```
{"element_1": 2, "element_2": 5, "element_3": 1, ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best approach.

```
def count_duplicates(l):
    
    count = {}
    for i in l:
        count[i] = count[i]+1 if i in count else 1
    return count
    
l = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5]

ans = count_duplicates(l)
print(ans)
```